# How do I delete content from a PDF file?

Tags: pdf

I've tried the first 5 or so results on Google for PDF editors, and none of them allow me to delete existing PDF content, they only allow me to add new content on top of the existing content.

I've also tried opening the PDF in LibreOffice Draw, but the text does not look correct and overflows.

How do I delete content from a PDF file?

Comment: I have always used OpenOffice, works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the free version of Acrobat pro 2017 here  https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/download-install/kb/acrobat-2017-downloads.html
and use the page editor for a week (as a trial)

Comment: @aaron-franke did this help?